# Create PDF from HTML + CSS using positioning

Tags: php, pdf

I want to create a PDF file from my PHP (HTML+CSS) but I positioning DIVs with CSS and I tried many PHP libs and no one could make me 100% same as HTML.

My positioned divs always under unpositioned items.

Can you tell me how can I position a picture and 2 text to a specified place of what kind of lib should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try wkhtmltopdf? http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ it is css3 complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was exporting HTML as a JPG file than use GD library to write PHP variables on it, than I used mPDF library to export as PDF.

Hope this way will help you to get the same as HTML.